# Send Array From Matlab To Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino

I would like to send more than 150 integers(16-bit) from Matlab(R2015a) to Arduino(Mega 2560). For this reason, I am sending those numbers in an array. However, the buffer size is 64 bytes. My solution is here: After Matlab writes the array to buffer, it waits a message(number) from Arduino. After Arduino reads the buffer, it sends a message(number) to the Matlab.

Matlab Code:

```
arduino=serial('COM5','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(arduino);
q=150;
X=rand(1,q);

d=floor(q/64);
r=rem(d,64);

n=1;
while(n<=d+1)

    if(n~=d+1)
        Z=[];
        for w=(64*(n-1)+1):64*n
            Z=[Z X(w)];
        end

        fprintf(arduino,'%d',Z);

        b1=fread(arduino,1);

        if(b1==99)
            n=n+1;
        end
    else
        Z=[];
        for w=1:r
            Z=[Z X(w)];
        end

        fprintf(arduino,'%d',Z);

        b2=fread(arduino,1);

        if(b2==99)
            n=n+1;
        end
    end       
end


fclose(arduino);
```

Arduino Code:

```
char matlabdata[64];
int index;
int mode=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(mode==0){
    if(Serial.available()>0){

       index = Serial.readBytesUntil(' ',matlabdata,64); 
       matlabdata[index] = '\0'; 
       mode=1;
    }    
  }

  else if(mode==1){
    Serial.write(B01100110);
    mode=0;
    for(int x=0; x<64;x++){
      matlabdata[x]='\0';
    }
  }

  Serial.flush();


}
```

Matlab Error:

```
Unexpected error: The number of bytes written must be less than or equal to OutputBufferSize-BytesToOutput..
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `serial.fprintf` you are writing text to your device, this requires one byte for each digit. From your description I assume that you want to write individual bytes, use [`serial.fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fwrite.html) for this purpose.

Comment: Daniel, I would like to write the array into buffer at one connection. How can I handle it with fwrite?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I would like to send the array to Arduino using buffer once.

Answer (score 0):

You should add OutputBufferSize,InputBufferSize, like this:

```
arduino=serial('COM7','BaudRate',115200,'OutputBufferSize',2400,'InputBufferSize',2400);
```

where '2400' is size of array.
Good luck !